# ConnectionError in Docker with Nodejs (Hapi.js) and Prisma

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, port, prisma

I would like to put my Nodejs app into a docker. When deploying it via npm run build and start I can send requests to it.
But when creating a docker image I getting problems:
First I have an EXPOSE 8080 in my Dockerfile. Then I am running `docker run -p=3000:8080 --env-file .env my-docker-file`. After that I am getting the info that the server is running on http://localhost:3000.
I know localhost:3000 ist just in the docker file. But at least the docker is running.

When I use the command `http localhost:3000` (or the browser) I am getting `http: error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')) while doing a GET request to URL: http://localhost:3000/`.

Does someone have an idea what's going wrong??? I have no clue.

tanks to all hints that directs me into the right direction.

My Dockerfile:

```js
## this is the stage one , also know as the build step

FROM node:12.17.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY src ./src/
COPY tests ./tests/

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

## this is stage two , where the app actually runs

FROM node:12.17.0-alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 8080
CMD npm start
```

Comment: can you please post your Dockerfile?

Comment: I did it :) hopefully you find a mistake

Comment: `After that I am getting the info that the server is running on http://localhost:3000`, you get the this info from container, but you bind 3000:8000, where 8000 comes from? 3000 is host port while 8000 should be container port...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Dockerfile, first you better to build your image.

```
FROM node:12.17.0-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npm run build

## this is stage two , where the app actually runs

FROM node:12.17.0-alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=builder /app/package*.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

From the location where your `Dockerfile` located:

`docker build -t your-image-name .`

`docker run -p 3000:8080 --env-file .env your-image-name`

Comment: Yeah that's the way I did it

Comment: I just copied your Dockerfile, but getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the IP address?

When i first deploy my Node project to Docker, i couldn't access it too, because my Node project was listening for `localhost` requests. But if you don't specify your network as host, your Docker container will have some other IP address in your subnet.

I've changed my Node projects listening IP address to `0.0.0.0` and after that i could connect to my Node project running in a Docker container.